# Broken Plugin: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've written a python plugin, and it works perfectly on my pc (Windows 7). I've zipped the whole folder and sent it to the client. they report back with this (the name of plugin's folder is LTS):

[image]

Any ideas why this happened? As far as I know they use Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a simple mistake on the client side. The original plugin was in a folder named "LTS", where within it "lts.py" had the main code.
They had changed the name of folder to "LTS_Previous" for some reason, and that was causing the "EOL" error.